# How to filter by the last element of a json array field in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-postgresql, django-jsonfield

I have a model `MyModel` with a `JSONField` called `data`. This json field contains an array of objects like:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-01-01",
        "amount": 120
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-01-02",
        "amount": 150
    }
]
```

I would like to filter by the `amount` of the last element of the array. From the Django documentation, I understand that I can filter by the first element using:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(data__0__amount__gte=100)
```

How could I do this using the last element?

Answer (score 2):

Django and Postgres' `->` operator are quite happy to use negative indices with semantics familiar from Python. So, you can say things like:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.values_list('data__-1__amount', flat=True)[0]
>>> 150
```

This works since `.values_list()` is string based.

But, since `.filter()` expects kwargs, and `data__-1__amount` is not a valid Python kwarg key, you need this form:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(**{'data__-1__amount__gte': 100})
```

Answer (score -3):

Filter returns always a list of objects even there is only one such object in this case greater than 100 which is stored in data field "data" of the same instance:

```
last = MyModel.objects.filter(amount__gte=last.data[-1]["amount"])
```